# lightning-card does not work but lightning:card works

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, sfdc-styleguide

I installed my first lwc open source project , I opened up [component reference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) 
specifically the [card component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example) in the Lightning Web Components section and not the aura components section and then component edited app.html 
entered this code in the app.html markup -

```
<template>
<lightning-card  title="Hello">
                <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
                <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

it showed me an error that said

> Failed to compile ./src/client/modules/my/app/app.html Module not
>   found: Could not resolve lightning/card as
>   D:\SALESFORCE\April15\MyFirstLWC-OSS\my-app\src\client\modules\lightning\card\cardundefined
>   This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

but then i opened the aura components , took reference from there and tried this ,

```
<template>
        <lightning:card  title="Hello">
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
        </lightning:card>
</template>
```

and the code worked , Now i can't seem to understand why lightning-card did'nt work but lightning:card did.

js controller code:-

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the basic js as well, once you include the `import {LightningElement} from ‘lwc’;` directive it should work.